# Res folders. Read file manually

Tags: java, android, xml

I have String.xml files organized by language inside my res folder like:

```
res/values
res/values-de
res/values-es
res/values-fr
res/values-ga
res/values-hi
res/values-it
...
```

By default the app make a choose according to device's language or by finding [Best Match](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch). Now, I want to include a language selector to let the user choose any of them. Is there a way to read those files without moving them to assets folder or any other place?
Is it something it can be done once or should I do it by every activity?

I found some "solutions", but they are not permanent nor clean since they need to be done on each activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never did it myself, but this thread looks promising, just in case you didn't find it.-

[Change language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android)